# Refresh token not working in gmail api in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, gmail, access-token, refresh-token

Access token automatically expires after 1 hour. After that code throws following exception, until I follow all the authorization process again manually, i.e. delete token file, run index.js again to generate new token.js. Index.js contains exact this code. [Index.JS Code](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/node-samples/blob/master/gmail/quickstart/index.js)

Exception
[image: Exception Image]

My question here is, that refresh-token isn't automatically working, how can I manually refresh it, if not automatically .
And can I increase access-token's expiry time manually? Or set to never expire?

Token.json
[image: Token]

My index.js to generate token file. I run it 1st time using node index.js, it generates token.json.
Index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the 
first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Gmail API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listLabels); 
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}




/**
 * Lists the labels in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listLabels(auth) {
  const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
  gmail.users.labels.list({
    userId: 'me',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const labels = res.data.labels;
    if (labels.length) {
      console.log('Labels:');
      labels.forEach((label) => {
        console.log(`- ${label.name}`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No labels found.');
    }
  });
}
```

here I access "access-token" , where I access mails from inbox like

```
var gmail = new Gmail("token-here")  
var allMails = gmail.messages('label:inbox label:unread has:attachment ', {max: 5})
```

Comment: please edit your question and include actual code not pictures of things.  We need to see your code and how you are refreshing the access token

Comment: @DaImTo please have a look now, I have added other code too. The problem is that my token is not getting refreshed. Don't know I had to do it manually or its written in index.js, but not getting executed.

Comment: auth/api is not refreshing token automatically. After 1 hour it starts giving above mentioned error

Answer (score 0):

You will always generate a new token once it expires. You can't use the same token again after it expires.

Comment: then whats the purpose of refresh-token in token.json?